# The chat room doesn't have an interesting name yet; shall we name it?

Tags: discussion, chat

Most of the private betas decide on a name for the main chat room.

Currently, its name is quite boring -  [elementary OS](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25374/elementary-os).

How would you name it? Post an answer and others can vote on it.

Answer (score 4):

### The Pantheon

Or something similar, indicating a meeting hall of deities.

Answer (score 3):

### elementary OS

Just keep it the same.

Comment: o.0​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @nicael feel free to vote either way for this one.

Answer (score 2):

### Chat.

In keeping with the elementary naming style ;)

Comment: I like this idea, but maybe lowercasing it would be better?

Comment: @r3bl aren't the apps on elementary in upper case?

Answer (score 0):

## 221B

[image: elementary]

> Elementary, my dear Watson

<sup><sub>it doesn't matter he never actually it</sub></sup>

Comment: Yes! 221B - that would be amazing!